# Excel VBA "Selection.Left"

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, excel-2016

I'm using an old spreadsheet with macros which works fine with Excel 2010, but throw an error (Run-time error 91) in Excel 2016. I should also mention that I have no experience with VBA.

I've narrowed the error down to:

```
With Worksheets("Worksheet_name")
   .Cells(17,1) = Selection.Left
   .Cells(18,1) = Selection.Top
End With
```

In particular it's `Selection.Left` and (I expect) `Selection.Top` which cause the problem. I've searched both the run-time error and `Selection.Left`, but can't find a fix for this problem. Is there an updated way to perform `Selection.Left` in Excel 2016?

I have no experience with VBA, so producing a MWE of the problem is beyond me (the original script is a few thousand lines and uncommented), but hopefully this is enough to understand the problem:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(1,360,210,30,30).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 1
Selection.Name = "Drag me"

Dim PointBox As Shape
Set PointBox = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("A", "B", "C", "Drag me")).Group
PointBox.Name = "pointx"

With Worksheets("Worksheet_name")
   .Cells(17,1) = Selection.Left
   .Cells(18,1) = Selection.Top
End With
```

Comment: What is selected while you run the code? And what are you trying to do with that code? And what is the exact error message you get and in which line do you get it?

Comment: "Worksheet_name" you probably misspelled sheet name.

Comment: The worksheet name is not mispelled, the worksheet exists and the macro, unedited, works on Excel 2010.

Comment: When running the code I don't know what is selected; hovering over "Selection.Left" doesn't give any values. I didn't write the original code, so I don't know what it's trying to do, I expect, it's trying to get the value in the cells to the left and above the selected cell.

The exact error message is: Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set. This happens due to the `Selection.Left`, replacing this with a dummy value of 1, the script runs fine, but of course the calculations will be wrong.

Comment: Please read [mcve]. The problem is that with the code you show we are unable to help you. `Selection.Left` gives no values but the distance from the selected cell to the left border of the table. So if a cell in column A is selected this gives `0` if a cell in column B is selected this gives the width of column A etc. If no cells are selected but any other objects (charts, buttons, etc), it gives the position of that object on the worksheet. So unless you can tell what `Selection` is (what is selected) we cannot help you.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I've updated the question, hopefully that provides a bit more context. I hadn't realised that Selection could be a number of different objects, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Try to replace `Selection` with `PointBox` and see if it works.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ That runs fine now, thanks.